# How to access data json array in php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I get this json data from football api

```
[
  {
    "id": "/sport/football/english-premier-league/everton-v-arsenal/32031876",
    "name": "Everton v Arsenal",
    "team1": {
      "name": "Everton",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "team2": {
      "name": "Arsenal",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "start_datetime": "2023-02-04 12:30:00 UTC",
    "is_live": false,
    "live_time": null,
    "odds": {
      "1": "7.500",
      "2": "1.444",
      "X": "4.333"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "/sport/football/english-premier-league/wolves-v-liverpool/32031228",
    "name": "Wolves v Liverpool",
    "team1": {
      "name": "Wolves",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "team2": {
      "name": "Liverpool",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "start_datetime": "2023-02-04 15:00:00 UTC",
    "is_live": false,
    "live_time": null,
    "odds": {
      "1": "4.100",
      "2": "1.833",
      "X": "3.900"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "/sport/football/english-premier-league/aston-villa-v-leicester/32031878",
    "name": "Aston Villa v Leicester",
    "team1": {
      "name": "Aston Villa",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "team2": {
      "name": "Leicester",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "start_datetime": "2023-02-04 15:00:00 UTC",
    "is_live": false,
    "live_time": null,
    "odds": {
      "1": "1.950",
      "2": "3.900",
      "X": "3.500"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "/sport/football/english-premier-league/brighton-v-bournemouth/32031880",
    "name": "Brighton v Bournemouth",
    "team1": {
      "name": "Brighton",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "team2": {
      "name": "Bournemouth",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "start_datetime": "2023-02-04 15:00:00 UTC",
    "is_live": false,
    "live_time": null,
    "odds": {
      "1": "1.333",
      "2": "9.000",
      "X": "5.000"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "/sport/football/english-premier-league/man-utd-v-crystal-palace/32031894",
    "name": "Man Utd v Crystal Palace",
    "team1": {
      "name": "Man Utd",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "team2": {
      "name": "Crystal Palace",
      "score": "",
      "sets": null,
      "games": null
    },
    "start_datetime": "2023-02-04 15:00:00 UTC",
    "is_live": false,
    "live_time": null,
    "odds": {
      "1": "1.364",
      "2": "9.500",
      "X": "5.000"
    }
  }
]
```

I want get specific data from json using php code my php code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://betfair-sportsbook.p.rapidapi.com/matches-by-competition?competitionid=%2Fsport%2Ffootball%2Fenglish-premier-league%2F10932509&lang=en",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "X-RapidAPI-Host: betfair-sportsbook.p.rapidapi.com",
        "X-RapidAPI-Key: 525b88983fmshf83037428bcd3a1p153499jsncc02a790c215"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

I want Out Put like this for all array :

Match Name : Everton Vs Arsenal
Start : 2023-02-04 12:30:00 UTC

I want Out Put like this for all array :

Match Name : Everton Vs Arsenal
Start : 2023-02-04 12:30:00 UTC

Comment: Json decode the response, loop over the array and pick `name` and `start_datetime` and print them.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode on the $response data.

https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_json_decode.asp

You can do something like this to turn that JSON object into an array: `json_decode($response, true);`

Then you can access the fields as you would any associative array.